# Duplicate emails being sent from php mail

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer

I have a cron task that looks like:

```
00 12 * * 1     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
45 20 * * 1     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
00 12 * * 2     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
45 20 * * 2     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
00 12 * * 3     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
45 20 * * 3     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
00 12 * * 4     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
45 20 * * 4     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
00 12 * * 5     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
45 20 * * 5     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
00 12 * * 6     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
45 20 * * 6     /usr/bin/php    /path/to/php/script/cron_job.php
```

The php code in that file looks like this:

```
$employeesArray = array(
    'employee1@company.com',
    'employee2@company.com',
    'employee3@company.com'
);

if (date('A', time()) == 'AM')
{
    foreach($employeesArray as $employee)
    {
        echo $employee.' - AM';

        $mail->
        addTo($employee)->
        setFrom('email@domain.com')->
        setHtml('Dont forget to Log In.');
        $result = $sendgrid->smtp->send($mail);

        echo ' -> '.$result.'<br />';
    }
} 
else 
{
    foreach($employeesArray as $employee)
    {
        echo $employee.' - PM';

        $mail->
        addTo($employee)->
        setFrom('email@domain.com')->
        setHtml('Dont forget to Log Out.');
        $result = $sendgrid->smtp->send($mail);

        echo ' -> '.$result.'<br />';
    }
}
```

This script is used to send all employees a message first thing in the morning before they start and just before their shift ends; only on Monday to Friday. The emails are going out, but Employee1 and Employee2 are receiving 4 copies of the message and Employee3 is receiving 7 copies. When I run the script manually by navigating to the page "cron_job.pnp" in a web browser it only sends once to each so I'm assuming it is a problem with my cron job firing more than once.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Side note: you can use `00 12 * * 1-6` to define `00 12` on days 1 to 6.

Comment: Are the messages multiple copies of the same message, or are they actually separate messages? Looking at the message id header will probably tell you, as it's quite likely that timestamps may be the same. If it's the former, it's more likely a problem with your mail server than cron.

Comment: @Synchro you were right, I am using an external SMTP server as a relay and they said there is an API that is recommended to avoid issues they are having with the mail() function. Works great now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing an `->addTo` call on every iteration of the loop. You're basically building up an array of addresses on every iteration..

```
iteration #1: 
   "To:" list is: (empty)
   add: user#1
   send()  (one email goes out)
iteration #2:
   "To:" list is: user #1
   add: user #2
   send() (two emails go out)
iteration #3
   "To:" list is: user #1, user #2
   add: user #3
   send() (three emails go out)
etc...
```

Since you've tagged this with PHPMailer, you need to `$mailer->ClearAddresses()` on every loop, so that the stored `To:` names get erased:

```
foreach($user as $user) {
   $mail->AddUser($user);
   $mail->send();
   $mail->ClearAddresses();
}
```

Comment: I'm actually using SendGrid Mailer now, but same principle applies. I removed the foreach() loop and am adding all addresses to the same message at once by using $mail->setTos($employeesArray), since the setTos() method accepts an array as a parameter.